# How to exactly create a CVE?

Tags: c, cve, heap-overflow

I found an heap overflow exploit for a vulnerability in git servers. This lead to lucrative operations on various bug bounty programs *(GitHub already promised to put me in their top 10)*.

When it was [corrected recently](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34fa79a6cde56d6d428ab0d3160cb094ebad3305), the case of remote code execution wasn’t identified.
As result, many Linux distributions as well as mainline commercial products like Apple osx still ship affected versions.

So, I think it’s time to make a great publicity around the vulnerability and that a CVE shared across all can would be the best way to achieve this.

This would just take age if I need to contact them all.

### Update :

For those seeking about the details, just wait my profile to appear on the [main page](https://bounty.github.com) of [this site](https://bounty.github.com). I also won’t attempt anything as long as the issue isn’t fixed with the vendor.

Comment: https://cve.mitre.org/cve/request_id.html is the formal documentation. Please be responsible with your disclosure, especially if you've found something as dangerous as you claim. Work with the vendors before releasing publically.

Comment: @Ohnana : I can’t talk with every vendors. I’m a student who is no longer on vacation *(next time is in february)*. I think it’s time to advertise *(as soon as the last bounty will be awarded to me)*.

Comment: MITRE is the top-most CNA. Talk to them, and see if they can help you. Unfortunately, disclosure done right takes time. CERT and other teams may be able to lighten your load.

Comment: @Ohnana : How can I talk to them ? I don’t even understant which [address I should e mail](https://nvd.nist.gov/contact.cfm) for that [one](https://nvd.nist.gov/contact.cfm).

Comment: https://cve.mitre.org/cve/cna.html#participating_cnas

Comment: @Ohnana : I don’t even understant which [address I should e mail](https://nvd.nist.gov/contact.cfm) for that [one](https://nvd.nist.gov/contact.cfm).

Comment: http://www.zerodayinitiative.com may help

Comment: @NeilSmithline they told they weren't intersted into that product.

Comment: As @Ohana mentioned, report the vulnerability to [CERT](https://forms.cert.org/VulReport/).  It's not an email, it's an online form. They'll coordinate with the vendor for you, and get a CVE number assigned.

Comment: @Xander : Git isn’t part of any vendor, and the issue is [already fixed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34fa79a6cde56d6d428ab0d3160cb094ebad3305). It’s just a possible exploit case wasn’t identified making older version looking as inoffensive.

Comment: It isn't magical self creating software.  It has maintainers, which are the same thing.

Comment: @Xander : The maintainers, are already aware of that case. They fixed the problem before they know about it, so their is nothing they can do.

Comment: Ok, so you don't need CERT to contact the maintainers for you then.  Do you still have a question?

Comment: @Xander : I’d like to know who to mail for [that one](https://nvd.nist.gov/contact.cfm).

Comment: You don't.  You fill out the CERT form I gave you a link to.

Comment: @Xander : the question doesn’t ask the exact process on how to create one.

Comment: @Xander : I didn’t got any replies from cert. even after telling them twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ohnana also mentioned the way to request a formal CVE is through their intake form.

https://cve.mitre.org/cve/request_id.html

Details from a current snapshot of that website

Main Methods
Contact one of the officially recognized [CVE Numbering Authorities (CNAs)](https://cve.mitre.org/cve/cna.html#participating_cnas), which will then include a CVE Identifier number in its initial public announcement about your new vulnerability.

Or, contact an emergency response team such as [CERT/CC](http://www.cert.org/), etc., post the information to mailing lists such as [Bugtraq](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1), or provide the information to a vulnerability analysis team.

Alternative Method
If you are unable to obtain a CVE Identifier number via the main methods above, you may request a CVE Identifier number directly from the CVE project. To reserve a CVE Identifier number before publicizing a new vulnerability, vulnerability researchers may contact cve-assign@mitre.org and we will provide you with our "CVE-ID Reservation Guidelines for Researchers" document. We will then work with you to assign a CVE Identifier number for the issue while you work through the process of publicly disclosing the vulnerability.

Please review the Researcher Responsibilities.
https://cve.mitre.org/cve/cna.html#researcher_responsibilities

Adding a link to the CVE FAQ.
https://cve.mitre.org/about/faqs.html

Comment: Once a ᴄᴠᴇ ɪᴅ is assigned and bug [fixed into master](https://bounty.github.com/researchers/ytrezq.html), how much time does it takes to get ᴄᴠᴇ details published ?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing as @user2284570. Can you add the info to your answer please?

Comment: At this time it appears there are no timeline guarantees for any part of the CVE ID granting process. I think it's because there are multiple CNA's and/or it's an internal process metric that doesn't appear to be documented publically.